# Espresso test: How to open my application back after opening the recent apps?

Tags: testing, android-espresso

I want to open my application back while writing an Espresso test case after opening recent apps by calling `pressRecentApps()` method.
Is there a way to do this except of simulating a click by coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that you can't. The moment your app loses focus, you are out of luck.

You can use [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) for that.

Comment: I achieved to this with Ui Automator, by finding the title and clicking on it. The bad thing that it just has API min level 18.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Espresso by calling the following:

```
val targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
val launchIntent = Intent(targetContext, NameOfTheActivityYouAreTesting::class.java)
activityTestRule.finishActivity()
activityTestRule.launchActivity(launchIntent)
```

I actually wrote a helper function for this:

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> ActivityTestRule<T>.restartActivity() {
  finishActivity()
  launchActivity(Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), T::class.java))
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
val activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(ActivityIAmTesting::class.java)

@Test
fun someEspressoTest() {

  // Some testing ...
  // ...

  activityTestRule.restartActivity()

  // Some more testing...
  // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) for this if you run your tests on an API level where the recent screen has application labels:

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
Context appContext = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
String appName = appContext.getString(appContext.getApplicationInfo().labelRes);
device.findObject(new UiSelector().text(appName)).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try UIAutomator. Tap recent apps twice to get back to your main application your Espresso is handling.

```
    uiDevice.pressRecentApps()
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    uiDevice.pressRecentApps()
    Thread.sleep(2000)
```

Comment: Good trick! Works for me, even with delay: `500L` between click and `1000L` after all.